# How to give id to point and draw line point to point using matplotlib.plyplot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I plot data using python. How to give id for each point in `plot` and then draw line from `A=(1,2)` to `B=(2,3)`

```
Lat=[1,2,3,4]
Long=[2,3,1,3]
id_point=[A,B,C,D]
plt.plot( Lat,Long , 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=4)
```

Comment: Can you try to draw your expected results? Something really simple in paint would do. It's a bit hard, for me at least, to understand what you want here. What is the id for each point to be used for?

Comment: for example I draw point A=(1,2) B=(2,3) C=(3,1) D=(4,3) using `plt.plot( Lat,Long , 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=4)`. When I call plt.show(). The point has no identity in paint, so I can't identify point in `plt.show()`. After that, I want to draw line from A to B.

Comment: Do you also want the names of the points in the plot? (added it in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```
def plotLine(p1, p2):
    plt.plot( [p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]] )

Lat = [1,2,3,4]
Long = [2,3,1,3]
id_point=['A','B','C','D']

# Fill a dictionary with the points
points = {} # Create empty dictionary
for idx, point in enumerate(zip(Lat,Long)):
    points[id_point[idx]] = point 

# Plot points and their names
plt.plot(Lat, Long,'o') #Plot the points as you did
for key in points:
    plt.annotate(key, xy=points[key]) #Print name of point

plotLine(points['A'], points['B']) #Connect point A and B
plt.show()
```

points is a dictionary with the following content:

```
{'A': (1, 2), 'C': (3, 1), 'D': (4, 3), 'B': (2, 3)}
```

The key is the name of the point and each value is a tuple with the coordinates.